# Asp.net 3.5 IIS 6 Remove server header from response

Tags: asp.net, iis, server

I have a website in Asp.net 3.5 and is hosted on IIS 6.
I'm not able to remove "Server" tag from response headers.

I tried creating HttpHandler, in which I 
 but I get error "This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode".
 I believe it's because of IIS and ASP.net version.

I tried adding lot of stuff in web configs and global asax but none is working. Can anyone please help me with it.

Is there any possible way I can remove Server tag from header.

Comment: IIS 6 is long dead. Use UrlScan https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/urlscan

Comment: We upgraded it. But thanks anyways